# Firebase (Firestore) not adding data and not throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application with basic crud operations to manage inventory. I am using firestore for this project. However, the data is not being added to my collection nor collection is being created. I could not find the error because seemingly everything is fine and no error is generated.
Even responses from Firebase website in networks tab were all 200.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code for AddItem.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { database } from "../../../Firebase";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";

export default function AddItem() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [vendor, setVendor] = useState("");
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [sessionMessage, setSessionMessage] = useState(false);

  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  const sub = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    //   Create a new item in database
    database
      .collection("items")
      .add({
        name: name,
        quantity: quantity,
        vendor: vendor,
        addedBy: currentUser.email,
      })
      .then((docRef) => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });

    setLoading(false);
    setSessionMessage("Created a new Item!");
    setName("");
    setQuantity("");
    setVendor("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      {sessionMessage && <Alert variant="info">{sessionMessage}</Alert>}
      <Form
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          sub(event);
        }}
      >
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Item Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            required
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="number"
            required
            value={quantity}
            onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Vendor Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            required
            value={vendor}
            onChange={(e) => setVendor(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <br />
        <Button
          disabled={loading}
          variant="primary"
          type="submit"
          className="w-100"
        >
          Add Item
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Infinite queries in networks tab (Update)
[image: Console Network Tab]

Here's the code for Firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSENGER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
export const database = app.firestore();
```

Comment: Can you try adding a log statement before the `.add()` and check if your `sub()` function is actually running ?

Comment: Have you created **items** collection in your FB?

Comment: I have not explicitly created the collection. I followed docs and tutorials as I am still learning, everywhere collection was created automatically.
However, I have tried this way too at one point. Doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I added a console log before `.add()` and it works just fine. Problem is still the same

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is exactly, but here's a hint:

Your `sub` method is not **async**, though the `add` method from Firestore returns a **Promise**. You are not "awaiting" the result from your database query to run the lines afterwards. That means your loader will disappear, the form will reset and the success message will be displayed before the object has been added.

Try changing it to this:

```
const sub = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    //   Create a new item in database
    const docRef = await database
      .collection("items")
      .add({
        name: name,
        quantity: quantity,
        vendor: vendor,
        addedBy: currentUser.email,
      });

    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);

    setLoading(false);
    setSessionMessage("Created a new Item!");
    setName("");
    setQuantity("");
    setVendor("");
  };
```

Hopefully you will get more insights on what goes wrong then!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried your method but after clicking, the button froze and nothing happened, Nothing got logged. But this method did gave me more insights! as I found something unusual in my network tab. Google firebase apis kept on running for infinity. I have attached the screen shot in original question. Have a look

Comment: Could you post what your "Firebase" file looks like (the one you import "database" from)?

Comment: Sure. Posted on the question.

Comment: Not a 100% sure as I only use firebase-admin, but have you tried `export const database = firebase.firestore();` instead of `export const database = app.firestore();` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Same problem. The database write call keeps sending requests (as in network console image) and its stuck in there forever.

Comment: So I don't see anything wrong with your code. My guess is that it's a problem with the submission of the form. Since you don't really submit the form (you use the React state), could you try removing the `onSubmit` from the `Form` element and write the `Button` like this: ```<Button disabled={loading} variant="primary" onClick={(e) => sub(e)} className="w-100">Add Item</Button>```